# can't access to ProperySource using external configuration in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i'm facing a problem with external configuration in my micro services project. when i access `http:localhost:8888/user-service/default`, i get the propertySource in the response:

```
{
   "name":"user-service",
   "profiles":[
      "default"
   ],
   "label":null,
   "version":"8f38f7c09c5128f09e3181f7b4c187b3ad0383ec",
   "state":null,
   "propertySources":[
      {
         "name":"file:///D:/Projects/Freelance/hanouti/config-server/src/main/resources/shared/user-service.yml",
         "source":{
            "spring.datasource.username":"....",
            "spring.datasource.password":"....",
            "spring.datasource.url":"jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/user_service_db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
            "spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size":25,
            "spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle":1,
            "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri":"http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/hanouti",
            "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id":"user-service",
            "spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret":"....",
            "keycloak.serverUrl":"http://localhost:8180/auth",
            "keycloak.realm":"hanouti",
            "eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address":true,
            "eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone":"http://localhost:8761/eureka/",
            "security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri":"http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
            "server.port":8001
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

but when i try to access it using @Value, it returns a null value.

this is my config class:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-id}")
    public String clientId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaquetoken.client-secret}")
    public String clientSecret;

    @Value("${keycloak.serverUrl}")
    public String serverUrl;

    @Value("${keycloak.realm}")
    public String realm;
}
```

EDIT :

the configuration is loaded by the user service and used for bootstraping

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access the values using `@Value` in the config-server itself? If not, is the `profiles.active` setup in `user-service` app correct ? When you give a file (`../shared/user-service.yml`) to config-server, it loads it for the client app with name `user-service`.

Comment: yes, configuration is loaded and used by the service, i edited my question, i want to access the values